# Bash script: Conditionally delete older files while keeping latest copies

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

Note: Though there's an answer from jeff-schaller, it depends on `zsh`; so I would like to get an answer based on `Bash`.

I like to create a Bash script to conditionally delete older files from a backup directory.

There are 2 conditions for 2 distinct file backups:

1, Keep the latest copy of `Edge_Profile_*.tgz`, and delete rest of `Edge_Profile_*.tgz` **only if they are older than 5 days**.

2, Keep the latest copy of `Firefox_Profile_*.tgz`, and delete rest of `Firefox_Profile_*.tgz`, **doesn't matter how old are they**.

Here's how I have modify this AskUbuntu answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/933098/928088

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

LOG_FILE="/home/admn/Cleanup.log"
TEMP_LOG="/tmp/Temp_Cleanup.log"

mv $LOG_FILE $TEMP_LOG

{

cd /home/admn/Downloads/Test;

echo "Cleanup log:" `date`

find /home/admn/Downloads/Test/Edge_Profile_*.tgz -type f \( -mtime +5 -printf 'Y\t' -o -printf 'N\t' \) -printf '%A@\t%p\0' |
    sort -zk2,2 | head -zn -1 | while read -r -d '' flag _ file; do \
        case "$flag" in 
            'Y') echo rm "$file" 
               ;; 
            *) echo "skipping $file (too new)"
               ;; 
        esac;
done

echo

find /home/admn/Downloads/Test/Firefox_Profile_*.tgz -type f \( -printf 'Y\t' -o -printf 'N\t' \) -printf '%A@\t%p\0' |
    sort -zk2,2 | head -zn -1 | while read -r -d '' flag _ file; do \
        case "$flag" in 
            'Y') echo rm "$file" 
               ;; 
            *) echo "skipping $file (too new)"
               ;; 
        esac        
done

} &>> $LOG_FILE

cat $TEMP_LOG >>$LOG_FILE

exit;
```

Output in the logfile with `echo`:

```
/usr/local/scripts/cleanup.sh

rm /home/admn/Downloads/Test/Edge_Profile_Jul_06_2021_00-35.tgz
rm /home/admn/Downloads/Test/Edge_Profile_Jul_07_2021_00-35.tgz
....
skipping /home/admn/Downloads/Test/Edge_Profile_Jul_12_2021_00-35.tgz (too new)
skipping /home/admn/Downloads/Test/Edge_Profile_Jul_13_2021_00-35.tgz (too new)
....

rm /home/admn/Downloads/Test/Firefox_Profile_Jul_01_2021_00-35.tgz
rm /home/admn/Downloads/Test/Firefox_Profile_Jul_02_2021_00-35.tgz
....
```

Output in the logfile while actually running the script, without `echo`:

```
/home/admn/Downloads/cleanup.sh: line 24: skipping /home/admn/Downloads/Test/Edge_Profile_Jul_12_2021_00-35.tgz (too new): No such file or directory
/home/admn/Downloads/cleanup.sh: line 24: skipping /home/admn/Downloads/Test/Edge_Profile_Jul_13_2021_00-35.tgz (too new): No such file or directory
....
```

Total files in the directory: 20 files

1, Edge_Profile_*.tgz: From July 06 to July 17: 12 files

2, Firefox_Profile_*.tgz: From July 01 to July 08: 8 files

**The issues**:

(1) I **think** the script is kind of working but I'm not sure as I've modified most part without knowing what's going on.

(2) Output to logfile:

I would prefer the exact same output in the logfile that I get with `echo`, except just the filenames (not with full path), like:

```
rm Edge_Profile_Jul_11_2021_00-35.tgz

skipping Edge_Profile_Jul_12_2021_00-35.tgz (too new)
```

OS: Ubuntu MATE 21.04

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Manipulating files based on their modification times is much easier in a shell that lets you access them directly. zsh is one such shell. Simply `sudo apt install zsh` to install it. Since your files appear to be in one directory, this answer is non-recursive. Demonstrating the simpler case first:

- To keep the latest copy of Firefox_Profile_*.tgz and delete rest of them no matter how old they are:

  ```
  echo would rm -v -- Firefox_Profile_*.tgz(.om[2,-1])
  ```

  Remove the `echo would`  portion if it looks correct. This uses a [glob (wildcard) qualifier](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#index-globbing_002c-qualifiers) inside the parenthesis to do three things:

  - select only plain files (not directories or sockets or etc) with `.`
  - order (sort) the files by their modification time, newest to oldest, with `om`
  - select a slice of the resulting list starting from the second element to the end -- skipping the first (newest) file, with `[2,-1]`

  If there are no matching files, zsh will stop and complain with "zsh: no matches found", and will not execute the `rm`.
- To keep the latest copy of Edge_Profile_*.tgz and delete the rest of them only if they are older than 5 days, first we grab the latest one:

  ```
  newest=(Edge_Profile_*.tgz(.om[1]))
  ```

  ... and then we get the ones that are older than five days:

  ```
  older=(Edge_Profile_*.tgz(.m+5))
  ```

  The new part here is the `+5` on the `m` modifier. That selects files that are older than 5 days. After that, we make sure the newest one isn't in the list to remove:

  ```
  remove=("${(@)older:|newest}")
  ```

  The new part here is the array subtraction symbol `:|`; it is documented in the [Parameter Expansion section of the zsh manual](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html). It selects the elements of "older" that are not in "newest". Finally, we remove that list of files:

  ```
  echo would rm -v -- "${remove[@]}"
  ```

Comment: Thank you for an answer, but I like to use `Bash`. 'Coz last time when I had installed `zsh`, I ended up with format and clean installation.

Comment: You don't have to use it as your day-to-day shell; just install it and use it for this one script.

Comment: oh okay, later I'm gonna try this, first in a VM. Thanks again.